# How to run Filter Curve EQ (Walkie-talkie) on folder (via script)?

Tags: audacity

I'm using `Audacity 3.1.3` (and windows)

I have folder: ("c:\f_files") which contains 1000 wav files.
for each file I want to run Walkie-talkie preset:
`(Effetct->Filter Curve EQ -> Manage -> Factory Presets -> Walkie-talkie)`

and save the results under ("c:\results")

How can I do it automatically (on all the 1000 files) ?